# Greedy for Cash

Tags: mathematics, alphametic

Solve this Cryptarithm

```
        GIVE
      + MORE
   ---------
       MONEY
```

<sub>Referenced from the Britannica Encyclopaedia No. 25 - "Number Prague"</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's clear that the V and the R are interchangeable so solutions are in pairs.

Here's a solution:

> 9376+1086 = 10462 or 9386+1076 = 10462

Here's another:

> 9476+1086 = 10562 or 9486+1076 = 10562

I believe these are the only solutions:

> 1. M is clearly 1.
>  2. O is therefore 0. It can't be 1 because it would then be a repeat and it can't be more than 1 because you can't get to 12 when you're adding M=1 to G.
>  3. G is therefore 8 or 9 with 1 or 0 carried.
>  4. I + 0 = N, so there must be a 1 carried in the I,O column and N=I+1. Which means we'll be looking for a solution that leaves two adjacent numbers unaccounted for.
>  5. Because of the carry, the V,R column must be bigger than 10. So the V,R column must come to 12,13,14,15,16,17.

We can then deal with these cases:

> 12: E=2 (so no carry). VR=(3,9),(4,8),(5,7)
>  We can eliminate (4,8) because Y will be 4. (3,9) and (5,7) don't work because G would have to be 8 in the former and you won't get the carry and you won't get two adjacent numbers with the latter.

Similar arguments eliminate other options until only:

> 16: E=6, VR=(7,8). There are then 3,4,5 as the only adjacent numbers left over leading to the two pairs of solutions shown.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the solution isn't unique.

> ```
>       9486
>     + 1076
>  ---------
>      10562
> ```

`I` could also be 3 if `N` is 4, and obviously V and R can be switched.

If, on the other hand, the puzzle had been `SEND + MORE = MONEY`, the puzzle would have been well known, [the solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbal_arithmetic) would have been unique, and the phrase more common.